# La funciòn LENGTH() no cuenta caracteres multi-bytes dentro de un procedimiento en mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Necesito crear una funcion que como salida debe, entre otras cosas, mostrar cuantos caracteres tienen determinados strings. Si bien en la documentacion de mysql la funcion LENGTH() se indica que cuenta los caracteres multi-byte, yo no puedo lograr que lo haga.

Adjunto un ejemplo que hice para probar esto. Que estoy haciendo mal? (es una exportacion de phpmyadmin)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `prueba`(`cadena` VARCHAR(256)) RETURNS longtext CHARSET latin1
    NO SQL
BEGIN

RETURN LENGTH(cadena);

END
This function returns:

SELECT prueba ("à");

prueba ("à")
=============
1
```

Comment: ¿El charset que utilizas no será el equivocado? ¿Has intentado cambiar el charset a utf 16?

Comment: No he intentado. Como lo cambio? Es a nivel variable input?

Comment: ¿Has probado CHAR_LENGTH() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length ?